# Creating SQL Server Agent Job in AWS RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

Hi gentle people of the internet,

I get the following error:
"Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "guest" does not exist,this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission."

I connect as the master user in SSMS. I checked and it has the "SQLAgentUserRole" role assigned. According to AWS documentation it should just work. Has anybody come across similar issues?

Many thanks[image]

Comment: What, precisely, are you attempting to do when this error pops up? Did you just open SSMS, or click on something, or attempt some task, or ??

Comment: I open up an EC2 instance, open SSMS there, context menu on the Agent's Jobs folder -> New Job...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the DB temporarily available for public and connected from my PC's SSMS. It worked without a problem.
This doesn't explain why the problem occures but serves as a workaround.

Comment: I've accepted my own workaround as an answer as I got no other.